# Use arrappend menthod in Redis to add an element to the beginning of array

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am using the redis arrAppend function in nodeJs and trying to add an element to the beginning of the array.

I have used this function it works well, but it adds the object to the end of the array.

```
await redis.json.arrAppend('noderedis', '.data', {
        id: 4,
        likes: 0
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.ARRINSERT](https://redis.io/commands/json.arrinsert/) command with the Index=0.

node-redis would expose this command as `redis.json.arrInsert()`

Comment: Hey yes this seemed to work.

used the following parameters
redis.json.arrInsert(:key, :path, 0, :data);

Comment: Still need to get reputations to do that. Please do consider upvoting my question